# How to permit editing of a many-to-many relationship in the django admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin, many-to-many

Have a class definition that looks something like this

```
class someClass(models.Model):
    field1 = models.ForeignKey('other_app.field4')
    field2 = models.ManyToManyField('other_app.field5')
    variable_name  = [1-char choices]
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=variable_name, blank=True)
```

When I try to edit this class in the admin panel, I get:

```
TypeError at /admin/[app]/[someClass]/add/
```

Assume it has to do with the ManytoMany field, any obvious workarounds?

---

**UPDATE**: Ok, so I figured out the issue: the code that my partner had written had an iterative `__str__` function:

```
def __str__(self):
    str_rep = '%s for ' % (self.field1)
    for p in self.field2:
        str_rep += str(p) + self.field3
```

Any ideas on how to rewrite this?

Comment: More exception details please.

Comment: `TypeError at /admin/[app]/[someClass]/add/

ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/[app]/[someClass]/add/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable`

Comment: Can you post the traceback? We're in the dark here! What's trying to iterate over a many related manager? Are you sure you haven't done something like `for i in someClass.field2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, try posting an actual traceback and the relevant lines of code. It would have shown us exactly where this code was breaking.

`field2` is not iterable. You need to get a `QuerySet` from your `ManyRelatedManager` by calling `all()` or `filter(...)`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships

```
def __str__(self):
    str_rep = '%s for ' % (self.field1)
    for p in self.field2.all():
        str_rep += str(p) + self.field3
```